# Send certain queries to a custom results page URL

Tags: search-results

Is it possible to send certain queries to a custom results page URL, and all other queries to the standard results page?  The criteria would be based on the query term matching an item in the term set.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE Veronica! I think you have a good start of a great question. However, if you could provide a little more detail to the question, such as the version of SharePoint 2007|2010|2013 Foundation|Standard|Enterprise and what kind of site collection|site|web your working with. That sort of basic information would help the community giving a better answer. Nice to see you here!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in SharePoint 2013 is using Query rules to trigger when Query terms match terms in Your term store, and perform specific actions like adding a result Group that displays Your results differently using special tailored display templates. These templates are based on html and JavaScript, so you may add Your redirect there...

What do you want to achieve?